# mediaelement.js to load video from php

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm trying to load video from php, using mediaelement.js , but its not working.. Its showing "Download File"

```
<video src="http://localhost/readmp4.php?id=111" width="640" height="360" id="player2" controls="controls">
<source type="video/mp4" src="http://localhost/readmp4.php?id=111" />
</video>
<script>
$('video').mediaelementplayer({});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent 1.5hours to troubleshoot why the mediaelement wasn't playing audio files returned from php.
darleys's suggestion worked but also adding type="audio/mpeg" also made it work.

`<audio src="stream.php?file=<?php echo urlencode($abs_file);?>" type="audio/mpeg" />`

Comment: Works great for <audio> tags, but be aware that the opener asked for <video>.

Answer (score -2):

1. Make sure to camouflage a mp4 as a path instead of a php request url
   for example `<video src=/junk/junk.mp4>  instead of <video src=video.php?name=junk>`
2. do a htaccess route to a php file, when user request a path route that to a php file that is going to read the video file secured in a location.
    for example ...

> RewriteRule ^junk/(.*) /preview.php?media=$1 [QSA,L]

1. now in php , make sure to cater to safari (ipad/iphone) request too...

   ```
   <?php
   class VideoGroup1 {
      public function preview() { 
          $id = substr($_REQUEST['media'],0,strrpos($_REQUEST['media'],"."));
          $thisMedia = Pillar_Manage_Media::fetchMedia($id);
          //echo Foundry_Useful::unsealit($thisMedia['path']).$thisMedia['mediaid'];
          $file = Foundry_Useful::unsealit($thisMedia['path']).$thisMedia['mediaid'].".mp4";
          $filesize = filesize($file);

          $offset = 0;
          $length = $filesize;

          if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']) ) {


              $partialContent = true;


              preg_match('/bytes=(\d+)-(\d+)?/', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $matches);

              $offset = intval($matches[1]);
              $length = intval($matches[2]) - $offset;
          } else {
              $partialContent = false;
          }

          $file = fopen($file, 'r');


          fseek($file, $offset);

          $data = fread($file, $length);

          fclose($file);

          if ( $partialContent ) {


              header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');

              header('Content-Range: bytes ' . $offset . '-' . ($offset + $length) . '/' . $filesize);
          }


          header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
          header('Content-Length: ' . $filesize);
          header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"');
          header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

          print($data);

      }//End Function preview


   }//END Class VideoGroup1
   ```